# Insert a section before Introduction in an article

Tags: sectioning, abstract

I would like to include a "Motivation" section after the Abstract and before Introduction in an article.  I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
\begin{Motivation}



\end{Motivation}
```

I know its weird to the professionals but I used the analogy of the abstract.

Comment: What's the problem with `\section*{Motivation}`?

Comment: The abstract is one of the very few predefined environments. Usualy, you don't rite stuff like `\begin{results} \end{results}` or similar in LaTeX. You just start a `\chapter` or  `\section` or one of the levels below.

Comment: @Egreg \section*{Motivation} works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to do

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}
\date{July 38, 2016} % don't ask why

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
This is the abstract.
\end{abstract}

\section*{Motivation}

We have several good reasons for writing this paper.
The main one is that ducks can fly.

\section{Introduction}

...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could simply use abstract environment twice, giving each abstract a different name

```
\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Motivation}
\begin{abstract}
    Some motivational text here
\end{abstract}

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
    No form, no name, simple existence.
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

I was assuming you didn't want to use a simple `\section` for your motivation

EDIT:

To have a "numberless" section all you need to do is use `\section*{Motivation}`

Comment: Thanks @Elad. Using the \section command gives the Motivation section a number (1. Motivation). I just tried the \renewcommand. it works but presents the title in an abstract style. I actually want the Motivation to be like a section but without numbering

Comment: Ah ! In that case see my edit, it's even easier :)